# Different SQL Datasource on Dropdownlist Selected Index Change

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sqldatasource

I have a Grid view and I want to use Two different Sql DataSources on Selecting different values from DropDownList i.e. On Selected Index Change.
Please help me How should I implement that???
I don't want to use Code behind to change the Data in Gridview....
Thanks in Advance

Comment: its possible to change your data source the way you need,that is by using drop down list selected index changed event .but without using code behind is not sure.i have read about writing codes using server tags,ie, like in this link" http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Different-Embedded-Code-Blocks-and-its-use-in-ASPNet.aspx  "  .why dont you chose an easy way by using code behind?

Comment: If you wan't the source dynamic, code behind is the best thing. What's the problem with using code behind?

Answer (score 0):

Without using code behind you cannot implement in this process ***so it is not possible***